# Create trapezoid with 45 degree uprights in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape

Following on to this question:
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1419870

I want to make a trapezoid with the uprights at 45 degrees.
So at step #5, how do I stop dragging when at 45?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though this question is better placed on the graphics SE, and there may be many different answers, I'll add my suggestion.

In order for this to work properly, convert the object to path.

Drag a guide diagonally and place it to intersect the corner of the rectangle. With snapping turned on, it will snap to the corner node.

[image: 45° guide]

Drag a second guide horizontally to the top of the rectangle:

[image: horizontal guide]

Drag the corner node to the intersection of the two guides:

[image: drag node]

Repeat for the other side. There may be other methods, but I think this one is easy enough.

In the example I've created, it doesn't make a trapezoid, but that's because the rectangle is not wide enough.

If you require angles other than 45°, double click on a guide and change the angle in the dialog box.